# Creating a Windows shortcut (shell link) in C++

Tags: c++, windows, lnk

I want to programmatically create a Windows shortcut (`.lnk` file) to a folder. To do this, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3907013/3764804) code snippet. However, I get the compilation error `C2371 'WebBrowser': redefinition; different basic types` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\exdisp.h line 2367`.

Is there a [C++17 `std::filesystem` API](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) for this? If not, how can I fix the compilation error from above? Even with cleaned up includes, the error persists:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlguid.h>
#include <shobjidl_core.h>
```

Using the [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command yields:
`The device does not support symbolic links.`
So that doesn't work either, maybe because this is an external SSD.

What else could I try?

Comment: I suggest asking another question which is focused just on the includes.  The error you are getting has nothing at all to do with the `IShellLink` interface or even COM.  Do you get the error with nothing at all in your program except the three `#include` lines in your question?  Might be time to repair-install your copy of the Windows SDK.

Comment: If you want to solve the question yourself, search for the identifier `WebBrowser` in the files you are including, and pay close attention to what `#if` guards are surrounding that code (you want to just skip over it, not needed for calling `IShellLink`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answer you linked to is the correct way.  And it does not rely on `WebBrowser` at all.  It will probably help to define some of the `NO_XXX` macros before including `windows.h`.

In *my* version of `ShlGuid.h` which is slightly older than yours, I see

```
#ifndef NO_SHDOCVW_GUIDS

#ifndef GUID_DEFS_ONLY
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <shldisp.h>
#endif
```

so you can use `NO_SHDOCVW_GUIDS` to excise the troublesome header that you weren't wanting anyway.

If you wanted support for WebBrowser and the kitchen sink, another fix might be moving `#include <windows.h>` after `ShlGuid.h`, as shown e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422757/103167

---

Links are something that differ a fair amount from filesystem to filesystem, so difficult to standardize.  Shell links (.lnk files) are filesystem-independent, but only work on MS Windows (completely non-portable) which also is a strike against finding support in a standard API.

Comment: Yes, `#define NO_SHDOCVW_GUIDS` fixed it